# Javascript Form Checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a javascript form with checkboxes on it.  When I click a checkbox and then click "print this page"  Everything prints but the checkmark in the checkbox that I selected.  Can you help me fix this?  thanks

Comment: What? Please revise your question.

Comment: Hmm?  Works for me in both IE and FF...

Comment: Hm, well for me as well it works in IE8 and FF3

Comment: Should be closed as "WORKSFORME" :P

Comment: Are you using an old version of IE8? I think it was a bug initially.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this bug report on Microsoft Connect:

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=434706

If you're using IE8 that could be the problem.

For those trying to reproduce the issue, it's important to note that only checkboxes whose state has been changed after the page loads seem to be affected.

**EDIT**:

I have successfully reproduced this on IE version 8.0.6001.18865.  On stackoverflow's prefs tab, I clicked "Hide Ignored Tags".  When I printed the page, the check mark did not appear.